# Apache not finding the HSM-protected private key over PKCS#11

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, openssl, mod-ssl

I have installed Apache on my Centos7 virtual machine together with mod_ssl. I'm trying to make TLS working with the private key protected by an HSM over PKCS#11, but when I try to start Apache it doesn't find my private key (see the error below). Also nothing gets written in the logs of our PKCS#11 library.

On the other hand if I try to use OpenSSL directly from the command line with the same PKCS#11 URI, it is able to communicate with the HSM backend and identify the key. Also logs of the PKCS#11 library appear.

```
openssl rsautl -engine pkcs11 -keyform engine -inkey 'pkcs11:type=private?pin-value=121212;token=VendorPKCS11;id=%51' -sign -in myinputfile.txt -out myoutputfile.txt
```

For me it looks like Apache is not loading our PKCS#11 library for some reason and I don't know why. I found [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/configuring-applications-to-use-cryptographic-hardware-through-pkcs-11_security-hardening#using-hsms-protecting-private-keys-in-apache-and-nginx_configuring-applications-to-use-cryptographic-hardware-through-pkcs-11) in Google but it is was not very detailed.

Here's what I have setup...

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf**:

(Note: apachecert.pem is self-signed using the private key on HSM.)

```
Listen 443 https

SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin

SSLCryptoDevice pkcs11

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName myserver:443

    ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
    TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
    LogLevel warn

    SSLEngine on

    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3

    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!SEED:!IDEA

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/apachecert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "pkcs11:type=private?pin-value=121212;token=VendorPKCS11;id=%51"
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf:**

```
openssl_conf = openssl_def
[openssl_def]
engines = engine_section
[engine_section]
pkcs11 = pkcs11_section
[pkcs11_section]
engine_id = pkcs11
dynamic_path = /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libpkcs11.so
MODULE_PATH = /etc/pki/tls/libVendorPKCS11.so
init = 0
```

**/etc/pki/tls/VendorPKCS11.properties:**

```
log.folder.path=/etc/pki/tls/p11logs
log.level=5
delay.between.auto.recovery.attempts=300
authentication.mode=TICKET
portal.server.list=node1
token.label=VendorPKCS11
token.manufacturer.id=Vendor
token.model=HSM Portal Token
token.serial.number=1
token.max.pin.length=1024
token.min.pin.length=1
token.hardware.version=1.0
token.firmware.version=1.0
slot.description=Vendor HSM Portal PKCS11
slot.manufacturer.id=Vendor
slot.hardware.version=1.0
slot.firmware.version=1.0
info.cryptoki.interface.version=2.20
info.manufacturer.id=Vendor
info.library.description=HSM Portal based PKCS11 library
info.library.version=2.0
credentials.user.name=username
portal.node1.uri=backendserver:8999
portal.node1.certificate.path=/etc/pki/tls/rootcer.pem
portal.node1.concurrent.clients=2
timeout.connection=15000
timeout.command=60000
timeout.keep.alive=600000
```

**The error I see when trying to start Apache:**

```
Oct 22 08:55:25 myserver systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Oct 22 08:55:25 myserver httpd[11013]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 112 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:
Oct 22 08:55:25 myserver httpd[11013]: SSLCertificateKeyFile: file '/etc/httpd/pkcs11:type=private?pin-value=121212;token=VendorPKCS11;id=%51' does not exist or is empty
Oct 22 08:55:25 myserver systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 22 08:55:25 myserver kill[11015]: kill: cannot find process ""
Oct 22 08:55:25 myserver systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 22 08:55:25 myserver systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Oct 22 08:55:25 myserver systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Oct 22 08:55:25 myserver systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

Does anyone has an idea why Apache is not able to find the vendor PKCS#11 library or at least any logs don't show up? Also I find it strange that in the error output of Apache, something adds "/etc/httpd/" in front of the PKCS#11 URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some gray hair I realized that PKCS#11 URIs are only implemented in the development branch of Apache (version 2.5.1). It is not available in the latest stable release of 2.4.

The revision including this feature is this: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1830819

So for now what I'm trying to achieve doesn't seem to be possible with Apache 2.4 and mod_ssl.

As the odd numbers in Apache minor version numbers are only considered Alpha/Beta, it seems we will need to wait for httpd 2.6 to be released. I couldn't find any information about that, so for now I will not hold my breath.

Alternative ways I've been investigating to use Apache with PKCS#11 are:

- Use mod_nss instead of mod_ssl
- Have a PKCS#11 module that is able to get the parameters from a fake key file (to have Apache 2.4 to read the ssl configuration without issues)

Comment: PKCS11 support was backported to httpd 2.4.42.